# rails form_tag with checkboxes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I know there may be 1 or 2 similar questions,but none of them helped me understand where I am wrong in the following.
I have the following haml form in my view:

```
= form_tag movies_path,:id=>"ratings_form", :method => :get do
  Include: 
  -  @all_ratings.each_with_index do |rating, index|
  = rating
  = check_box_tag "ratings[]", rating, @selected_ratings.include?(rating), id:"ratings_#{rating}"
```

and in my controller:

```
def index
    sorting=params[:sorting_on_a_column]
    if sorting=='1'
       @sort='title'
       @movies=Movie.order('title')
    elsif sorting=='2'
       @sort='date'
       @movies=Movie.order('release_date')
    else
       @movies=Movie.all
    end
    @all_ratings=Movie.select(:rating).map(&:rating).uniq
    @selected_ratings = (params["ratings"].present? ? params["ratings"] : @all_ratings)
    @movies = @movies.where(":rating IN (?)", params["ratings"]) if params["ratings"].present? and params["ratings"].any?
     end
```

My target on the above is to sort movies by title or release_date(which it does) and also show only the movies that correspond to the checked checkboxes.I am new to Ruby and Rails, so I would really appreciate your help.Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few things to think about:

1 - How many possible ratings are there? You're assigning `@all_ratings` based on what appears in another model's database table. If there isn't a Rating model, and the complete list of ratings will grow over time, there probably should be.

2 - You can set up your check box tag like this:

```
- @all_ratings.each_with_index do |rating, index|
  = label_tag "rating_#{rating}", rating
  = check_box_tag "ratings[]", rating, @selected_ratings.include?(rating), id: "rating_#{rating}"
```

This will give you an array of string values in `params["ratings"]` that should work in your code as-is.

The label tag is set up so that when you click on the text, it selects the appropriate check box. `.each_with_index` is used to provide a unique ID for each rating, since as of now, they don't have one from the database (it matches the `"rating_#{index}"` id declaration in the `check_box_tag`).

Comment: First of all,thanks for your time.So I edited the above as you said(I only skipped the functionality of clicking on the text of checkboxes),but it still does not work.It says that the method where is undefined for Array

Comment: I managed to make it work in a different way,but 1 up for your help(when I reach rep 15 :D)